# A not-existing column should not break the sql query within select

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case there are different database versions (SQL Server). For example my table `orders` does have the column `htmltext` in version A, but in version B the column `htmltext` is missing.

```
Select [order_id], [order_date], [htmltext] from orders
```

I've got a huge (really huge statement), which is required to access to the column `htmltext`, if exists.

I know, I could do a `if exists` condition with two `begin + end` areas. But this would be very ugly, because my huge query would be twice in my whole SQL script (which contains a lot of huge statements).

Is there any possibility to select the column - but if the column not exists, it will be still ignored (or set to "null") instead of throwing an error (similar to the isnull() function)?

Thank you!

Comment: No. The shape of a query in SQL is fixed. The columns and tables it accesses are fixed. The columns it produces are fixed. If you really want to go down this route, you'd be looking at dynamic SQL where you actually build up a customized query as a massive string and then execute it (so, it's a different query each time, and doesn't contradict my previous comments)

Comment: And even with your proposed `if exists` and `else` proposal, you'd have to enclose the query that references the missing column in a string and separately execute it - T-SQL would attempt to compile the *whole* batch and fail due to the missing column, before it even started *executing* the batch and reach the `if exists` test.

Comment: good idea :) then I think it's the best way to build up an tsql query. thank you!

Comment: Why are you using same application code to access different database versions? It's going to be neverending task to try to cope with every difference in databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a View in both the versions..

In the version where the column htmltext exists then create it as

```
Create view vw_Table1 
AS
select * from <your Table>
```

In the version where the htmlText does not exist then create it as

```
Create view vw_Table1 
AS
select *,NULL as htmlText from <your Table>
```

Now, in your application code, you can safely use this view instead of the table itself and it behaves exactly as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

First thing why a column would be missing? definitely its been deleted somewhere. if so, then the delete process must have updated/fixed the dependencies.

Instead fixing it after breaking, its better to do smart move by adopting some protocols before breaking anything.

`IF Exists` is a workaround that can help to keep queries running but its an overhead considering your huge database and queries

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to approach this is to check if the column exists in your database or not, and build your SQL query dynamically based on that information. I doubt if there is a more proper way to do this.

Checking if a column exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.columns 
WHERE  Name = N'columnName' 
AND    Object_ID = Object_ID(N'tableName');
```

For more information: [Dynamic SQL Statements in SQL Server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/generate-dynamic-sql-statements-in-sql-server/306)