# T-SQL Using Unsupported Column In Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to query cluster node information from SQL Server 2008 R2 and up using the following query.

```
select
nodename node,
status status_value,
status_description status_text,
case when is_current_owner = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end is_current_owner
from sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes
```

This works fine on SQL Serve 2012 and up but on 2008 R2 according to the sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187341(v=sql.105).aspx) it looks like the status and status_description aren't available.

Is it possible to run the query on 2008 R2 and fill in values for the unsupported columns?  I tried using case statements to detect the SQL Server Version and print a default value else the 2012 column. It seems like if the status or status description columns are present anywhere in the query, then the query fails with invalid column.

Comment: You can use a dynamic query instead and only add those columns if you they exist

Comment: If you don't have too many servers you could create views like on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358983/a-not-existing-column-should-not-break-the-sql-query-within-select)

Comment: Queries have to be *compiled* and optimized in their entirety before they start executing. The absence of a column causes a compilation failure, so you don't get to have an runtime behaviour that avoids the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ask the server what version it is and do something different depending on the response.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

IF (SELECT left(cast(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as char(10)),2) )='12'
BEGIN

SELECT @sql = @sql +

'
select
nodename node,
status status_value,
status_description status_text,
case when is_current_owner = 1 then ''true'' else ''false'' end is_current_owner
from sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes'
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @sql= @sql +
'
select
nodename node,
'''' as status_value,
'''' as status_text,

case when is_current_owner = 1 then ''true'' else ''false'' end as is_current_owner
from sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes

'
END

select @sql 
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: This will fail to *compile*. You'd need to put the query that accesses (potentially) non-existent columns into a different scope (e.g. as a string inside `EXEC`) than the one which performs the check for existence.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  Whoops, tested on the wrong server.  Will correct

Comment: This compiles, but is_current_owner is not valid in the environment I have for testing.